# AutoGPT Traceback errors when running python -m autogpt

Tags: python, pip, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

OSX Ventura 13.2.1
Apple M1

I'm trying to get AutoGPT running on Mac.
Following this tutorial:
https://bytexd.com/getting-started-with-auto-gpt-for-beginners-setup-usage/

When I run python I get the following Traceback error.

```
{23-04-18 15:32}ryans-mbp:\~/Dev/Auto-GPT@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ ryanriggin% python -m autogpt

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main return _run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/Users/ryanriggin/Dev/Auto-GPT/autogpt/main.py", line 2, in <module> import autogpt.cli File "/Users/ryanriggin/Dev/Auto-    GPT/autogpt/cli.py", line 2, in <module> import click ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'
```

I'm guessing this is a problem with pip or the way I have python installed.

```
Here is some info that may be useful:
{23-04-18 15:39}ryans-mbp:~/Dev/Auto-GPT@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ ryanriggin% python --version
Python 3.9.6
{23-04-18 15:39}ryans-mbp:~/Dev/Auto-GPT@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ ryanriggin% which python    
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
{23-04-18 15:39}ryans-mbp:~/Dev/Auto-GPT@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ ryanriggin%
```

Comment: Did you run pip install -r requirements.txt?

Comment: I did, and it executed successfully.  Here is a screenshot of the output. https://share.cleanshot.com/SyPWpHQF

Comment: Some other notes  about my system if helpful.  I'm using Homebrew.

Comment: This is my zshrc file it if helps: 
https://hastebin.com/share/amiwuvilic.bash

Comment: I thought maybe it was something to do with my xcode install.  this is what I see there if helpful:  

(autogpt) {23-04-18 20:27}ryans-mbp:~/Dev ryanriggin% xcode-select -p

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
(autogpt) {23-04-18 20:27}ryans-mbp:~/Dev ryanriggin%

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by running

pip install -r requirements.txt

Thanks to https://github.com/jrecasens95 on Github for the assist.
https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT/issues/2472

Comment: Nice. virtual venv would probably prevent this. Unless using them already

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because you are running python3.9 try to update it to 3.11. if its already installed change the path of python3 to 3.11